Evaluating GLM with Gamma distribution vs. transformed response for predicting right-skewed price data
I am trying to predict house prices using a dataset with the following variables:
'data.frame':   9800 obs. of  6 variables:
$ bathrooms   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ bedrooms    : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ pets_allowed: Factor w/ 4 levels "Cats","Cats,Dogs",..: 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 4 4 4 ...
$ price       : int  1390 925 2475 1495 1695 1560 1560 1000 950 625 ...
$ square_feet : int  107 116 130 138 190 200 200 200 200 200 ...
$ region      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Midwest","Northeast",..: 3 4 2 4 4 3 3 3 4 3 ...

The price variable is right-skewed, so I first tried fitting a GLM with a Gamma distribution and log link:
model2 <- glm(price ~ bathrooms + square_feet + region, data = usa, family = Gamma(link = 'log'))

After performing forward, backward and best subset selection, I ended up with bathrooms, square_feet and region as the predictors.
The model summary looks reasonable, with all predictors highly significant. The variance inflation factors are also all < 5, suggesting no major multicollinearity issues:
My main question is: Does this GLM with a Gamma distribution seem like a good fit for the data based on the model summary and VIF values?
Call:
glm(formula = price ~ bathrooms + square_feet + region, family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
    data = usa)

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     6.549e+00  1.147e-02 571.209  < 2e-16 ***
bathrooms       1.234e-01  1.041e-02  11.859  < 2e-16 ***
square_feet     3.366e-04  1.238e-05  27.197  < 2e-16 ***
regionNortheast 4.456e-01  1.438e-02  30.982  < 2e-16 ***
regionSouth     6.763e-02  9.914e-03   6.822 9.52e-12 ***
regionWest      5.058e-01  1.109e-02  45.606  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.1441117)

    Null deviance: 2300.3  on 9799  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1215.2  on 9794  degrees of freedom
AIC: 148140

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4




"After performing forward, backward and best subset selection" ... "all predictors highly significant" ... if you're doing that on the same data you selected the final model on, your regression output is largely nonsense. The coefficient estimates of the included variables are biased (away from 0), the standard errors biased toward 0, p-values biased toward 0, etc

(... or glm output, etc)
